# I want to create a personal site in Sub site level( Same as we create My site Host)

Tags: sub-site, team-sites, personalization

Can we create  a personal site at Sub site level. I searched in internet all solution saying to create a new site collection, that I don't want .

I want to create same in my team site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't. The whole point of a personal (MySite) site is that it is a silo not connected to anything else. That’s why you get a Site Collection usually under the wildcard inclusion /personal of the MySite Host root Site Collection.

To accomplish this effect you need to build/configure something of your own. But since there are a lot of dependencies to MySite when it’s in use, I would recommend not to.